# Bootstrap/Javascript - Check boxes if selected one, else unselect all

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need some help because I'm stuck.

So basically I have this:

```
$(function() {
$('.turn_on').on("click", function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var $otherChecks = $('.check_1, .check_2');
$otherChecks.removeAttr('disabled', checked);
});
});

$('.turn_on').change(function () {
if(this.checked){
var $otherChecks = $('.check_1, .check_2');
$otherChecks.removeAttr('disabled', checked);
}else{
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var $otherChecks1 = $('.check_1, .check_2');
$otherChecks1.removeAttr('disabled', checked);
}
});

<form method="post">
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="turn_on" value="turn_on" class="turn_on">Turn on</label>
<br>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="check_1" value="check_1" class="check_1" disabled>Option 1</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="check_2" value="check_2" class="check_2" disabled>Option 2</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

The first script works fine, but the script with "change" doesn't work.
Basically what this does is when user checks the box "turn_on" it "undisables" all the other checkboxes.

I also have all the divs and scripts right.
It's just the code doesn't work on change.

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: What PHP part? @Epodax

Comment: You tagged your question with php

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
   $('.turn_on').on('change', function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked")){
        var $otherChecks = $('.check_1, .check_2');
        $otherChecks.removeAttr('disabled', checked);
      }else{
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var $otherChecks1 = $('.check_1, .check_2');
        $otherChecks1.removeAttr('disabled', checked);
     }
   });
```

If you say that the code works, but the change function do not? try above code, and comment if there is still issues?

you are missing the $() around your "this"

EDIT - NEW ANSWER. 
When enable/disable, you should really use prop() insted - I have created a fiddle for you, where it checks and unchecks.

```
$(function() {
 $('.turn_on').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")){
    var $otherChecks = $('.check_1, .check_2');
    $otherChecks.prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
  console.log('unchecked');
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var $otherChecks1 = $('.check_1, .check_2');
    $otherChecks1.prop( "disabled", true );
 }
 });
});
```

If i misunderstood you, and you still want it to always remove the disabled, then just set it to true, instead of false. 
also, if you want to remove the checkmarks, just prop("check", false);
fiddle for testing is here : https://jsfiddle.net/embtpspL/1/

Comment: @PatrykCz.  I dont think that you have asked the question right? 
I have created a fiddle for you, where it disables and enables.
If this is what you want, then comment here, so that i can change my answer. - Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/embtpspL/1/